# without using webview instagram sign in android Application?

Tags: android, integration, instagram-api

i need to integrate Instagram sign in my Android App ?
 How to perform sign in with Instagram credentials in android without navigating user to Instagram website using Webiview?

Somebody already did this in their android app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.dimi.instapro&hl=en
exactly i want to do like this.. i want to build this as a native app..

Suggestions needed, Awaiting Responses.. *Thanks in Advance*

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Instagram developer's documentation,they seems to provide a quite rich API for login from third party apps

[Instagram Login API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/)

Thers's also an AndroidWrapper Library for Instagram API,which helps you to sign in to instagram and access it's endpoints

Link to Library : [AndroidInstagram](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidInstagram)

Upon that, you may find this tutorial(uses webview) [usefull](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/instagram-integration-android-application-tutorial)

Comment: Please note that link-only answers are discouraged. You could improve this answer by editing in the essential parts of the linked pages. Then, the answer will no longer rely on the link; you can keep the links for reference.

Comment: yeah i already tried this tutorial.. i loads the Instagram web login in webview, that i have clearly mentioned in question, without using webview..

Comment: have you tried their API ? just found this on github,seems it fits the bill : https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidInstagram...

Comment: what abt the library AndroidInstagram ?

Comment: @al_mukthar yes ! that library using the same like web views

Comment: yes,i understand that sorry...i was bit busy in office work...just shared the link when glanced this question

Comment: @Keerthivasan,have u tried instagram official API which has oauth login?if yes,post the code